# Another proof of the comparison principle for PDEs by the theory of viscosity solutions

Tags: parabolic-pde, fractional-calculus, alternative-proof

In my research I study (fully) nonlinear PDEs with fractional derivatives. For an analysis of these, I use the theory of viscosity solutions.

So I am now at the end of my tether becasuse I can not prove a comparison principle (in short C.P.).
In the proof argument of C.P. in the theory of viscosity solutions, the *doublling variable method* is usually used but for my subject this seems not to work well.
Almost papers related this topic prove C.P. by modifying slightly the above argument.
And so it might be able to prove if I repeat a correction, but I can hardly hope.

> **My question (hope)**:
>   If you know, please tell me some papers that proof arguments independing on the above one is written. In addition, I am glad if nonlocal equations are discussed.
>   I think there are no such papers but I want to depend on those.
>   By the way, because my equation is not level set equation, I mention that arguments by the level set method do not work as well.

Thank you in advance.